# What is the correct method to receive UDP data from several clients synchronously?

Tags: udp, client-server, listener

I have 1 server and several (maybe up to 20) clients. All clients are sending UDP datagram at random time. Each datagram is quite short (about 10B), but I must make sure all the data from each client is received correctly.

If I let all clients send datagram to the same port, and client B sends it datagram at the exact time when the server is receiving data from client A, it seems the server will miss the data from client A.

So what's the correct method to do this job? Do I need to create a listener for each of the 20 clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you bind a UDP socket to a port, the networking stack will allocate a buffer for a finite number of  incoming UDP packets for you, so that (assuming you call recv() in a relatively timely manner), no incoming packets should get lost.

If you want see your buffer size in terminal, you can take a look at:

```
/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default for recv
```

and

```
/proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default for send
```

I think the default buffer size on Linux is 131071B.

On Linux, you can change the UDP buffer size (e.g. to 26214400) by (as root):

```
 sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=26214400
```

You can also make it permanent by adding this line to /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.core.rmem_max=26214400
```

Since each packet is only 10B, shouldnt be a problem.

If you are still worried about packet loss you could implement a protocol where your client waits for a ACK from the server or it will resend. Many protocols use such a feature, but this is only possible if timing allows it. For example in streaming data it is not useful because there is no time to resend.

or consider using tcp ( if it is an option)